# Get custom policy name based on authorisation code

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using Active Directory B2C to authenticate users. We are leveraging on code flow.
We have 3 custom policies defined and each of them has it's own token endpoint.

I would like to dynamically infer the token endpoint based the the code received e.g.

```
https://<tenant domain>/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=<here goes the policy name>
```

**Is it possible to infer that based on the authorisation code?**

I was looking into to, but it looks like there is nothing inside telling the policy name. Literally it's just few basic info in header in JSON format and bunch of other characters that are not base64 encoded.

Comment: You should be able to see it when you parse the token.

Comment: The problem is, that I need to infer that before I ask for the token because I want to generate token endpoint and policy name is required in there.

Comment: Did it return id token when you got the authorization code?

Comment: No, I am only getting the code param.
The response type of authorisation request is `response_type=code`

Comment: Why don’t you use a library? Otherwise your app makes a call to /authorise so surely you have the policy id in memory. Give more details of what you’re implementing.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT not sure what library you have on mind. We tried to use spring-security-oauth, but our logic is heavily customised so even though we are modeling the logic based on that library, we had to write the solution on our own.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we came with a different solution but I can share the idea that worked for above problem.

When a user starts a custom policy we pass it to state query parameter. Then when B2C calls code endpoint with provided state parameter we read the policy name from it and use it to build the right token endpoint.